# Aggregate pandas df to get max and min as column

Tags: pandas

My dataframe is below:

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'c1':10,'c2':100,'c3':100}, {'c1':10,'c2':100,'c3':110}, {'c1':10,'c2':100,'c3':120}, {'c1':11,'c2':100,'c3':100}, {'c1':11,'c2':100,'c3':110}, {'c1':11,'c2':100, 'c3':120}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
```

This is how I am aggregating

```
new_df = df.groupby(['c1', 'c2']).agg({"c3": [min,max]})
```

But the output is not as per my expectation. My expectation is as below:

```
inp = [{'c1':10, 'c2':100,'c3_min':100, 'c3_max':120},  {'c1':11, 'c2':100,'c3_min':100, 'c3_max':120}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
```

What am I doing wrong? how can I reach my expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
# tell Pandas to use the vectorized functions with `'min', 'max'` 
# instead of `min` and `max`
new_df = df.groupby('c1', as_index=False)['c2'].agg(['min','max'])
```

Or to match the output:

```
new_df = (df.groupby('c1')['c2']
            .agg(['min','max'])
            .add_prefix('c2_')
            .reset_index()
         )
```

Comment: same story `df.groupby(['c1','c2'])['c3'].agg...)`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to keep your current code and flatten the index with [`pandas.MultiIndex.to_flat_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_flat_index.html)
:

```
# Flatten the column index
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.to_flat_index()

# From tuples to string
new_df.rename(columns='_'.join, inplace=True)

# Reset the index
new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Prints:

```
   c1  c2_min  c2_max
0  10     100     120
1  11     100     120
```